# cloud-init cc_mounts.py ignores AWS EFS mounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, mount, cloud-init

I am deploying an Amazon Linux AMI to EC2, and have the following directive in my `user_data`:

```
packages:
  - amazon-efs-utils

mounts:
  - [ "fs-12345678:/", "/mnt/efs", "efs", "tls", "0", "0" ]
```

I am expecting this to add the appropriate line to my `/etc/fstab` and mount the Amazon EFS filesystem. However, this does not work. Instead I see the following in my `/var/log/cloud-init.log` log file:

```
May 10 15:16:51 cloud-init[2524]: cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to determine the real name of fs-12345678:/
May 10 15:16:51 cloud-init[2524]: cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Ignoring nonexistent named mount fs-12345678:/
May 10 15:16:51 cloud-init[2524]: cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: changed fs-12345678:/ => None
```

If I manually add the expected entry to my `/etc/fstab`, I can indeed mount the filesystem as expected.

I've found a couple of bugs online that talk about similar things, but they're all either not *quite* the same problem, or they claim to be patched and fixed.

I need this filesystem to be mounted by the time I start executing scripts via the `cloud_final_modules` stage, so it would be highly desirable to have the `mount:` directive work rather than having to do nasty hacky things in my later startup scripts.

Can anybody suggest what I am doing wrong, or if this is just not supported?

Comment: Also seems to be a generic [issue with NFS mounts](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1870370), fixed in v20+

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that the cloud-init mount module does not support the efs "device" name.